# How to integrate a dresser with movable drawer in UE4?

Tags: texture, maya

I modeled a dresser in Maya. Right now it is divided in 19 objects. The drawer faces are copy and have their own unique place in the UVs and the knobs and back drawers are instances and are stacked on top of each other in the UVs. I want each drawer to be movable in UE4 and I don't know how to proceed. Should I combine the drawers together and have 6 object and another 1 for the frames? I will do the texturing process using Ddo.

I'm a little confused on how to proceed when I want to include moving part to and object but keeping everything on the same UVs.

How could I achieve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD.SE. It is very unlikely that this question is going to get answered, because the community do not deal with 3D.  I suggest you ask somewhere else which has a better chance of getting answers. This is just a heads up. Unfortunately there is no place for 3d questions like this in the stackexchange network one is currently being built but hasn't [passed to beta yet](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics).

Comment: You may also consider [GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for a question like this since you are dealing with UE4.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you can just have a separate object for each drawer, but have them all assigned to the same shader.  There is no reason why they can't share the same UV texture space, with the texture just having a space for where the drawer textures are and a separate space for the frame/knobs.